# C jansson encoding(?) issue with json_pack & json_dumps

Tags: c

I have this simple code snippet:

```
char acks[20] = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";

json_t *data;
data = json_pack("{si}", "acks", acks);
rdata = json_dumps(data, JSON_COMPACT);
printf("data:%s", rdata);
```

The printf result is not what I expected. It is something like:

> data:{"acks":2129192940}

I'm not sure if this is related with an encoding issue. Any hints?

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: @PaulBentley I was expecting to have data:{"acks":1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Comment: `{"acks": 1,2,3,4,5}` isn't valid JSON - this library would never output it.  `{si}` implies a string then an integer.  I think you may need to get rid of the `i` leaving `{si`}`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
data = json_pack("{siiii}", "acks", acks[0], acks[1], acks[2], acks[3])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.